# How can I replace the file's streams to fprintf/fscanf correctly?

Tags: c++, printf, filestream

I have the program with fstreams (it works correct)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
T abs(T x)
{
    return x < 0 ? -x : x;
}

struct point
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // FILE *in  = fopen("in.txt", "r"), 
    //      *out = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    // if (!in or !out) exit(1);

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    ifstream fin("in.txt");
    ofstream fout("out.txt");

    int n;

    //fscanf(in, "%d", &n);

    fin >> n;

    long double S = 0.0;

    vector <point> v(n);
    double minx = 1, miny = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        // fscanf(in, "%e%e", &(v[i].x), &(v[i].y));

        fin >> v[i].x >> v[i].y;
    }
    //...

    // fprintf(out, "%e", abs(S));

    fout << abs(S);
}
```

But when I uncommented it (and comment the streams off) I get a wrong result.

What do I doing wrong? 
Maybe I'm using a uncorrect modificators with fscanf/fprintf?

**UPD**

input : 4 0 0 3 0 1 1 0 3

**output with streams :**

3  (correct)

**with fscanf :**

-5.143241e+303

**UPD2**

I conducted a little study:
When I replace `%e` to `%le` I get `-2.000000e+000` 
Result is negative, althougth I using `abs()`, because I think this due that `fprintf` interpeting `lond double` wrong.

Whether possible to print `long double` using `*printf`?

Comment: Why not just stick with the streams since this is C++?  Are you trying to gain performance?

Comment: @NathanOliver, No, simply I want to make it as quickly as possible :)

Comment: @ It is just experiment. So, what I doing wrong? I'm confused...

Comment: Please show your actual and expected output.

Comment: Maybe it's because of S has `long double` type, and `%e` is cualifier for `double`? Than how qualifier should me do with `long double ?

Comment: Try to read with `"lf"` or `"le"` for double arguments. `"f"`, `"e"` are for float.